# NFS share from OS X Snow Leopard to Ubuntu Linux

Tags: linux, macos, nfs

I'm trying to share a some files on a Mac running Snow Leopard with a Ubuntu Linux.

The mount request gets a "permission denied", and a client system log contains 
"host xx requires a stronger authentication"

I've seen this problem referred to elsewhere, but no solution.  This is a hack on
a home network, and I really do want to "just do it" and damn the security flaws.

Answer (score 5):

Same error here, except that the Linux instance is running in a virtual machine ([QEMU](http://qemu.org)).  Adding `-o nfsvers=3` does not help; `mount -v` clearly shows that protocol negotiation is occurring and successful.

The problem is that the mount request comes from an unprivileged port; putting

```
nfs.server.mount.require_resv_port = 0
```

in `/etc/nfs.conf` on the Mac and notifying the running server (`sudo nfsd update`) fixes it for me.

Note: here is what the man page has to say about that option—and its security implications:

```
 nfs.server.mount.require_resv_port
          This option controls whether MOUNT requests are required to
          originate from a reserved port (port < 1024).  The default value
          is 1 (yes).  Many NFS server implementations require this
          because of the false belief that this requirement increases
          security.
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using NFSv4, which implements kerberos.  Try specifying the nfs version for 3 in your mount command & see if it works.  Also, you do know that UID/GID's need to be identical on both systems right?

Comment: You need to specify nfsvers=3.